# Getting ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID after installing SSL Certificate on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I followed this tutorial: https://www.onepagezen.com/free-ssl-certificate-wordpress-google-cloud-bitnami/ to implement SSL Certificate for my website on Google Cloud Platform. Now that I'm opening it I'm getting `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` and I've done everything right.

All of my certificates .pem files are in my website's folder (madnumber.org) and not in example.com that I've ensured.

My Configuration file is: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`

here is the code:

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion>
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  ServerName www.madnumber.org
  ServerAlias madnumber.org
  Redirect permanent / https://www.madnumber.org/
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

UPDATE:
Following a new tutorial https://techmonger.github.io/46/free-ssl-google-cloud/ but it's giving me this error:

> Domain: madnumber.org    Type:   unauthorized    Detail: Invalid
>   response from
>   http://madnumber.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/1OlqUItVV8q_MTc-vkFp53nifCBtcVNftFDyRmdxKYY
>   [00.00.00.0000]: "\n
>   lang=\"en-US\">\n\n\t\n\t
>   name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial"    To fix
>   these errors, please make sure that your domain name was    entered
>   correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain    contain(s)
>   the right IP address.

Comment: Post your certificates in your question. Do NOT post your private key file. Also include your Apache configuration file where you are actually using the certificates and private key. Otherwise we just have to guess what is wrong.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've updated the question and added the .conf file please have a look If this is not the case please let me know where can I find the `Apache configuration file where the certificates and private key are.`

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this error because of any of below mentioned three reasons:

1. The certificate issued has already expired
2. The Browser is old
3. The website certificate and browser connection are not secure

You can also refer this [resource](https://www.digitbin.com/neterr-cert-invalid-chrome-fix/).